# How to remove additional information from json

Tags: c#

When I want deserialize my json to ObservableCollection I have an error:

> Additional information: '`!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->`
>
> `<script type="text/javascript"`
>   `src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>`
>
> `<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->`
>
> ' is not a valid JSON primitive. This error can also occur when
>   extraneous data is present after the JSON data.

How remove this? There's not in a browser. This is my code:

```
String url = "http://...php";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            _events = (ObservableCollection<Event>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
```

Comment: What is in `stream`?  According to the error, it contains information that isn't JSON.  It looks like HTML.  You can't deserialize JSON if you don't have JSON in the first place.

Comment: Maybe use an HTML parser to parse out the chunk that contains the JSON you're looking for?  Hard to tell without seeing the entire response..

Comment: In a browser I have: [{"id":"4","name":"event1","date":"11\/15\/2015","time":"14:52:00","description":"blabla","cost":"3","freeplacesnum":"1","street":"A","city":"A","streetnumber":"3","type":"Cinema","latitude":"1","longitude":"1","login":"Login"}] 
In my app I have additional:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code --> 
after this code: 
String url = "http://.php";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string Result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
JsonTextBlock.Text = Result;

Comment: In a browser I had commercial banner too. That's the reason?

Comment: Are you saying the response you get in your web browser is different than the one you get in your C# code?  Or are they the same?

Comment: Yes, is different. When I run script on browser I have clear json from echo. But I must switch off banner from my free hosting. I think that this additional text is from this banner.

Comment: Looks that way.  I guess whatever code generates the banner doesn't respect the content-type of the response.  I'd research that code more and see if there's a way to temporarily switch it off based on URL, HTTP header, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It's good solution:

```
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            int index = stream.IndexOf('<');
            stream = stream.Substring(0, index);

            _events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Event>>(stream);
```

I cut a piece of a this json which start with "<".